# Solving a two variable integration

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, integration

I was going through the solid state book by Philip Phillips. I came across an integral similar to:

$$\int_{0}^{\beta}d\tau d\tau^{'}e^{-E_c|\tau-\tau^{'}|}$$

where $\beta E_c >> 1$.

I am not able to solve this integral. I am not sure how to deal with the |  | sign occurring in the exponent of e. Can anyone please help?

Comment: what are the limits for $\tau$, $\tau'$ ?

Comment: it is 0 to $\beta$ for both of them

Comment: is $\beta\gt 0$?

Comment: the integral is in a square so try integrating in two regions $\tau\gt\tau'$ and $\tau\lt\tau'$

Comment: $\approx\beta/E_c$

Comment: For each value of $\tau$, the integral on $\tau^{\prime}$ can be split into the sum of an integral from $0$ to $\tau$  plus an integral from $\tau$  to $\beta$. in each of those two integral the difference $\tau^{\prime}-\tau$ has a constant sign and you may get rid of the absolute value....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Divide the region of integration into two triangular regions I and II. The diagonal is $\tau=\tau'$. The original integral is the sum of these two sub-integrals.

[image: fig 1]

**In region I**

here $\tau\gt\tau'$, therefore 
$$
\begin{align}
I_I &=\int_{0}^{\beta}d\tau\int_{0}^{\tau} d\tau^{'}e^{-E_c(\tau-\tau^{'})}\\
 &=\frac{e^{-E_c \beta}+\beta E_c-1}{E_c^2}
\end{align}
$$

**In region 2**

here $\tau\lt\tau'$, therefore

$$
\begin{align}
I_{II} &=\int_{0}^{\beta}d\tau\int_{\tau}^{\beta} d\tau^{'}e^{+E_c(\tau-\tau^{'})}\\
 &=\frac{e^{-E_c \beta}+\beta E_c-1}{E_c^2}\\
&=I_I
\end{align}
$$

therefore the original integral

$$I=I_I+I_{II}=\frac{2(e^{-E_c \beta}+\beta E_c-1)}{E_c^2}$$

which under $E_c\beta \gg 1$ reduces to
$$2\frac{\beta}{E_c}$$